# @WebService jaxws - how to get namespace on method not soap envelope

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to create a @WebService with java 8 and jax-ws. However, I can't seem to find combination that will move the xmls "http://com.test.mymethod/mymethod" off of the envelope and onto the method. Instead every method I try adds it to the Envbelope and then puts ser: prefix before the MyWebmethod. (which would be good if I was creating and sending out wsdl but I have to match request format already in use elsewhere)

desired request format:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <MyWebmethod xmlns="http://com.test.mymethod/mymethod">
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to change something along the lines of `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="...." xmlns:ns1="http://com.test..."><s:Body><ns1:MyWebMethod...>` to your given example?

Comment: by default jaxws webservice seems to put all namespaces on the envelope then prefix everything below it, I was wondering if there was a way to move say the MyWebMethod namespace to that element then not have the prefix in sub elements MyWebMethod

Answer (score 0):

I think the only feasible way to to this (apart from asking: "Why is a semantically identical response not desired?" - but I am afraid of the answer :-) ) would be to "post-process" the response.

The obvious solution would be to define a `SOAPHandler`for the Service-Endpoint. This should be a straight-forward process:

1. Grab a sample response from your service (let's call this the "input XML" for the following steps).
2. Create a XSL Template to transform your input XML to the desired output form.
3. Annotate your `@Webservice` with a `@HandlerChain` annotation.
4. Create the handler chain .xml file to define your SOAP handler (there is a basic example of the whole process of defining handlers over at mkyong: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/)
5. Use your XSLT from step 2 in the SOAP handler to transfrom the response's DOM.

That being said - I am not 100% positive that you will be able to sufficiently influence the output of the handler chain. There is a very real chance that the resulting textual representation after the application server has serialized your DOM is still non-satisfactory.

The second option would be to define a `ServletFilter`and have it rewrite the textual output of your webservice endpoint. That will most certainly give you complete control over the output form - but at the (significant) cost of regenerating a DOM to feed into you XSL template.

All in all: *Why would you go through all the pain?* I am seriously curious.